# CANopen SDO normal download

Tags: embedded, can-bus, canopen

[image]

After initiating an SDO normal (segmented) download protocol like above, can a client receive any heartbeat message or irrelevant [CAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) message to our download protocol from the server at any time while the download protocol is still in progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the SDO transaction is between the client and the server on the defined message IDs, and so any other messages may legitimately exist within these transactions (on other message IDs), and things like hearbeats and PDOs continue to function in parallel to an SDO transaction. A typical timeout period for a requested response from an SDO server is 500 ms. This is way too long to stop doing all the other tasks required of the CAN bus.

There is no reason why you can't have concurrent SDO transactions between different node servers and clients as well. The only big SDO NO-NO is starting a new transaction on a server before the previous one has completed. That is sure to result in an SDO error.